# User received Strunk and White a month after his last edit

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

I just noticed that Diago was awarded a Strunk and White badge one month after his last edit.

What happened? Did the requirements for the badge loosen? Did it just take a month to award it?  Or is this an error?

Comment: **Conspiracy!**

Comment: @Weblog, I forgot to add that one in my list of possible causes...

Comment: Most likely a bug prevented him from getting it before (the bug must have been fixed a month later)

Comment: [Possibly related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59086/slow-motion-tumbleweed)?

Answer (score 6):

Not knowing how the badge system works, this is only hearsay.

Each time an action occurs that could affect a badge, the badge criteria are re-evaluated. This means that undeletions could create badges for apparently no reason. Theoretical timeline:

1. Edits question. (edits: 99)
2. Question deleted. (*counted* edits: 98)
3. Edits other question. (*counted* edits: 99)
4. Question undeleted. (*counted* edits: 100)

TaDa! Suddenly he gets [Strunk and White] without having made an edit for over a month. I assume this could also work for Good Answer badges.

Comment: duh, it's criteria.  Remember, a cafeteria is an amalgam of many cafeterions.  Wait, no...

Comment: (Seriously though, criteria is the plural.)

Comment: @PopularDemand Its especially funny because [criterium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criterium) is a word.

Comment: If this comment thread makes no sense to you, see the revision history.